# Converting JS object to json string using JSON.stringify

Tags: javascript

I have four textboxes which contain json string which I create by calling json.stringify on various js objects..

```
eg. '["users.name","users.username"]' (This is the value of one textbox)
```

What I want to do is create a single json string from these four json strings and send them to the backend using POST..

So I create a object and add them like this

```
tmp = {}
tmp["columns"] = $("#sc").val();
/*adding more data....*/

$.ajax("/api/backend", {
        data: JSON.stringify(tmp),
       /* more ajax code...*/
    });
```

The data that gets sent is of the following format..

```
{"columns":"[\"users.name\",\"users.username\"]"}
```

This is not a string but a json object...

Now when I do the following..

```
tmp1=  JSON.stringify(tmp)
```

and Post using..

```
$.ajax("/api/backend", {
data: JSON.stringify(tmp1),
/*more code below..*/
```

The data that gets sent is of the following format and is string..

```
"{\"columns\":\"[\\\"users.name\\\",\\\"users.username\\\"]\"}"
```

This string has a lot of '\' characters which needs to be taken into account in the backend.

Is this the right way of handling my problem or am I doing something wrong?

Thanks

Comment: I think the main question is, why do you have serialized data in the textboxes?

Comment: What are you actually trying to send?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on what you are trying to achieve.

If you want to send to the server a JSON that combines all JSON in your inputs, you'd better parse the JSON in your inputs, prior to adding them to you `tmp` object.  That way, you get an object containing objects, rather than an object containing JSON strings.

Retrieving JSON from inputs would be like this:

```
tmp["columns"] = JSON.parse($("#sc").val());
```

See that you are storing objects within your `tmp` object, rather than JSON strings.  Then, you can just send that object as JSON to your server.

Thus, your server would receive this:

```
"{\"columns\":\"[\"users.name\",\"users.username\"]\"}"
```

Which, I believe, looks much better.  I hope that helps.

Comment: I did the JSON.Parse as per your suggestion and removed tmp1=  JSON.stringify(tmp) and went back to data: JSON.stringify(tmp) but it sends json obj and not string

Comment: now data structure is {"columns":"["users.name","users.username"]"}

Comment: I added tmp1= JSON.stringify(tmp) and its working..tx